# Linking to revision diffs

Tags: feature-request, revisions

It's possible to link to certain revisions of a post. For example, [here](https://superuser.com/posts/378607/revisions) I can copy links to [revision 1](https://superuser.com/revisions/378607/1) and [revision 2](https://superuser.com/revisions/378607/2).

Unfortunately, it is *not* possible to link to the *diff* between two revisions, which is effectively a combined diff/changelog through the editor's comment.

When referencing the contents of certain *edits* (as opposed to the posts), this feature would be useful. Be it on Meta discussions, [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=2846448#2846448), or in the comments of a post discussing (e.g. [community-wiki](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki)) changes to a post.

---

A simple implementation would be to add anchors to the revisions list that allows us to link to the diff creating revision 2, as e.g. https://superuser.com/posts/378607/revisions#revision-2.

Please allow linking to certain entries in the revisions list by changing `<span title="revision 2">2</span>` to something like `<span title="revision 2"><a name="revision-2">2</span>`.

Add some minimal JavaScript to automatically expand the linked revision if it's not by default.

Comment: When would you want to do this?

Comment: @soandos When discussing edits on Meta or chat. For example, my chat comment referencing the revision 1/2 diff is broken now. I don't have more concrete examples right now, but I could see something like this *simply being used* once available. It's not something that has a lot of unexpected side effects, because *revisions* can already be linked to anyway.

Comment: It'd also be useful when discussing a specific change in a post's comment thread on the main site. Especially community-wiki (e.g. the *May 25 '11 at 6:25* comment [here](http://superuser.com/a/284351/22317) would have profited from linking http://superuser.com/posts/284351/revisions#revision-10), but also when others edit (and sometimes break) my posts.